# Clickable row in GridView and edit the row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row, edit

I have a problem here regarding to editable gridview. what I want to do is replacing edit button function by using a single clickable row. When I click a row, it should be forwarding me to a new page for editing those row data. How can I achieve this, without using edit button?

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // only apply changes if its DataRow

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        // when mouse is over the row, save original color to new attribute, and change it to highlight yellow color

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover",
        "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#EEFF00'");



        // when mouse leaves the row, change the bg color to its original value   

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout",
        "this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;");            

    }
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string abc = ((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='Default.aspx?id=" + abc + "'";
        //e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='Default.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CategoryID") + "'";         

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");

    }

}
```

Comment: I have test your code with me, its working as expected. I can't see any issue.

Comment: @V4Vendetta my current page is default2.aspx. The problem is Default.aspx is not in editing mode, just a plain page with gridview data on it. cannot edit anything.

Comment: @Muhammad my Default.aspx cannot edit anything. It should be editable, right?

Comment: There is no code related to that at all ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta You get me wrong here.What I want is when the row is clicked, it will prompt to default.aspx page. This page should be in edit mode, like when we click edit button. the row data that I selected should be able to be edited here. Any suggestions, or should I use rowCommand or anything?

Comment: do you have details view for editing record in Default.aspx page ?

Comment: @Com.Man.Do.Girl: What control will the page where you will edit the row use? FormView?

Comment: @Muhammad It's easy to put it this way..What should I have to add in order to accomplish similar task doing by edit and delete link in gridview using clickable row? I know the above coding is right but not finish.thanks.

Comment: @R anything will do as long as it is working. Currently using gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add controls as you want to Default.aspx and on default.aspx pageload event(In not postback condition) retrieve the record through ID and populate the controls.

Now when submit button pressed update the record and redirect back to your original page